# How to solve the given differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the given differential equation?

$\ (2x^2 +3y^2-7)xdx-(3x^2+2y^2-8)ydy=0 $

I have tried making the substituion $\ x^2+ y^2 =t$ but it wasn't of much help.Moreover, it isn't exactly a Homogenous DE.

Comment: Hint: read $\ (2x^2 +3y^2-7)d(x^2)-(3x^2+2y^2-8)d(y^2)=0 $.

Comment: Oh that was so simple.Thanks . I shouldn't have missed that.

Comment: Yep, but your are not done yet :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I got the final expression required. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps one of you could post the answer? I would be interested to see $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: Coul you post  *the final expression required* ? Just curious to see it ! Thanks

Comment: Notice that : $dN/dy = dM/dx$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\ {(x^2+y^2-3)}={(x^2+y^2-1)}^5 C$  After the hint given by Yves, you can put $\ x^2=a$ and $\ y^2 =b$ to further simplify the expression.